# Observer and inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm working on an observer pattern project and it seems like my classes aren't inheriting correctly. My ObserverChild class has a function update that takes an object of type Observable*, seen here:

```
class ObserverChild : public Observer {
    void update(Observable* o) {
         // code here
     }
}
```

My UpperCaseMonitor class is inheriting correctly, I think

```
class UpperCaseMonitor : public Observable {
    // implement class
}
```

When I complie everything, this is what error I get:

`monitor.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void UpperCaseMonitor::notify()’:
monitor.cpp:29:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘Observer::update(UpperCaseMonitor&)’
    (*it)->update(*this);`

`*it` refers to the iterator I'm using in a for loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
(*it)->update(this);
```

*this is getting the object, you need to pass the pointer

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you! It compiles just fine now.

Comment: Apparently they won't let you until 10 minutes have passed. What a strange requirement.

Comment: damn StackOverflow, damn! :D